# call a function after each() loop is completed

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each

I have an issue with displaying an array contains the values that have been saved during each loop.

This is the simple code illustrating what i mean

```
$('.photo').each(function(){
   width_array.push($(this).width()); 
});

// when each loop is complete
for(var i =0,i<$('.photo').length,i++){
   total_width += width_array[i];
}
```

The problem here is the for loop starts before finishing of each loop.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: This is only possible if `width_array.push()` does something using AJAX. There's something else going on, and we don't have enough code to analyze it for you.

Comment: I don't use ajax anywhere

Comment: Please [accept answers to your previous questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), as it encourages others to help you in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer using for loop instead of each function.

```
for(var i=0; i<$('.photo').length; i++)
{
  width_array.push($('.photo').eq(i).width());
  if(i==($('.photo').length-1))
   {
     for(var j =0;j<$('.photo').length;j++)
      {
       total_width += width_array[j];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this is a smart way, I'll try this method

Answer (score 0):

There's no way I can see that the `for` loop would begin before the `.each()` loop ends. Perhaps you forgot to declare `width_array` before the `.each()` callback function?

Either way, it'd be easier to just compute `total_width` inside the `.each()` loop:

```
var width_array = [],
    total_width = 0;
$('.photo').each(function(){
   width_array.push($(this).width()); 
   total_width += $(this).width();
});
```

Comment: this is an example, but the actual problem is setting a div width depending on the total width of the images

Comment: Please post the actual code in the future, or at least an example you can [show](http://jsfiddle.net) recreates your problem.